# C++ compare floats

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have designed a class to perform float compare. I used Knuth's strong compare to do it. Float compare is really really tricky, I'm sure there's something wrong :) Any comments?

```
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <assert.h>

class FloatUtils {
private:
    FloatUtils();
    template<typename T>
    static T safeDivision( const T& f1, const T& f2 );
public:
    template<typename T>
    static bool almostEqual( const T& a, const T& b, const T& relEpsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon(),const T& absEpsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()) noexcept;
    template<typename T>
    static bool almostZero( const T& a, const T& absEpsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() ) noexcept;
};

template<typename T>
inline T FloatUtils::safeDivision( const T& f1, const T& f2 ) {
    // Avoid overflow.
    if ( (f2 < static_cast<T>(1)) && (f1 > f2 * std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) )
        return std::numeric_limits<T>::max();

    // Avoid underflow.
    if ( (f1 == static_cast<T>(0)) || ((f2 > static_cast<T>(1)) && (f1 < f2 * std::numeric_limits<T>::min())) )
        return static_cast<T>(0);

    return f1 / f2;
}

template<typename T>
inline bool FloatUtils::almostEqual( const T& a, const T& b, const T& relEpsilon, const T& absEpsilon ) noexcept {
    static_assert(!std::is_integral<T>::value, "T can be only no integral type");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559, "IEEE754 supported only");
  
    if ( !std::isfinite(a) || !std::isfinite(b) ) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * avoid division by zero checking exactly 0 value
     */
    if ( a == 0 ) {
        return almostZero(b, absEpsilon);
    }

    /**
     * avoid division by zero checking exactly 0 value
     */
    if ( b == 0 ) {
        return almostZero(a, absEpsilon);
    }

    /**
     * We use Knuth's formula modified, i.e. the right side of inequations may cause underflow,
     * to prevent this, the formula scales the difference rather than epsilon.
     * We don't nanage 0 or Inf here so we need to add the special cases above.
     */
    T diff = std::abs(a - b);
    T d1 = safeDivision<T>(diff, std::abs(a));
    T d2 = safeDivision<T>(diff, std::abs(b));

    return d1 <= relEpsilon && d2 <= relEpsilon;
}

template<typename T>
inline bool FloatUtils::almostZero( const T& a, const T& absEpsilon ) noexcept {
    if ( std::abs(a) <= absEpsilon )
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Test cases:

```
int main() {
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(3.145646, 3.145646) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(145697.78965, 145553.09186, 0.001) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(145697.78965, 145552.09186, 0.001) == false);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(0.00001, 0.0, 0.1, 0.001) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(1.0, 1.0, 0.0) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(0.0, 1E-20, 1E-5) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(0.0, 1E-30, 1E-5) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(0.0, -1E-10, 0.1, 1E-9) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(0.0, -1E-10, 0.1, 1E-11) == false);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(0.123456, 0.123457, 1E-6) == false);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(0.123456, 0.123457, 1E-3) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(0.123456, -0.123457, 1E-3) == false);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(1.23456E28, 1.23457E28, 1E-3) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(1.23456E-10, 1.23457E-10, 1E-3) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(1.111E-10, 1.112E-10, 0.000899) == false);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(1.111E-10, 1.112E-10, 0.1) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(1.0, 1.0001, 1.1E-2) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(1.0002, 1.0001, 1.1E-2) == true);
assert(FloatUtils::almostEqual(1.0, 1.0002, 1.1E-4) == false);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that anyone trying to "fuzzy compare" floating-point numbers for "approximate equality" is already in a state of sin. In real code, either you care about *actual* (bit-for-bit) equality, or else you have a specific error-bar in mind which you've carried through the whole calculation. There's pretty much no situation where the programmer ever wants "`x` is approximately equal to `y`, based on some fudge-factor epsilons I don't even care enough to specify." That's just not a thing people want to do.

---

```
class FloatUtils {
private:
    FloatUtils();
```

You're using a struct instead of a namespace because you don't like namespaces, right? But then you're *also* giving it a private, non-defined constructor so that the user can't accidentally create an instance of the struct type itself? First of all, this is massive overkill and you should just write either

```
namespace FloatUtils {
```

or

```
struct FloatUtils {
```

But, if you really *must* prevent people from constructing instances of your type, the correct way to do that is not with a *private* constructor but instead with a *deleted* constructor:

```
struct FloatUtils {
    FloatUtils() = delete;
```

---

I don't see why you need `safeDivision` to be private. Couldn't it profitably be made public?

---

```
template<typename T>
static bool almostEqual( const T& a, const T& b, const T& relEpsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon(),const T& absEpsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()) noexcept;
```

This line is comically long, and also [default function arguments are the devil](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/04/18/default-function-arguments-are-the-devil/). It would be strictly better to write one declaration per signature to which you intend the user to have access:

```
template<class T>
static bool almostEqual(const T& a, const T& b) {
    auto eps = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();
    return almostEqual(a, b, eps, eps);
}

template<class T>
static bool almostEqual(const T& a, const T& b, const T& relEps) {
    return almostEqual(a, b, relEps, std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon());
}

template<class T>
static bool almostEqual(const T& a, const T& b, const T& relEps, const T& absEps);
```

Marking these functions `noexcept` doesn't serve any purpose; nobody is going to be making compile-time decisions based on whether `noexcept(almostEqual(a, b))`.

---

It is mildly strange that you consider `almostEqual(INFINITY, INFINITY) == false`. They're bitwise the same value; shouldn't they be considered equal?

---

```
static_assert(!std::is_integral<T>::value, "T can be only no integral type");
```

I suspect you mean

```
static_assert(std::is_floating_point_v<T>, "T must be a floating-point type");
```

---

Why do you need `safeDivision` to protect against overflow? It might well be that `abs(a - b)` is `INFINITY`, and so `diff / abs(a)` is also `INFINITY`... but that's definitely going to be greater than `absEpsilon`, so who cares?

Vice versa, I suggest that if `a > 0 && b < 0`, the numbers are *definitely not* approximately equal... well, not for many applications, anyway. Depends if you're using them as operands to `+` or as operands to `*`, I guess. Again, anyone comparing floats for fuzzy equality is already in a state of sin.

---

```
T diff = std::abs(a - b);
T d1 = safeDivision<T>(diff, std::abs(a));
T d2 = safeDivision<T>(diff, std::abs(b));

return d1 <= relEpsilon && d2 <= relEpsilon;
```

It seems like you could save a division by doing

```
T diff = std::abs(a - b);
T denominator = std::min(std::abs(a), std::abs(b));
return safeDivision(diff, denominator) <= relEpsilon;
```

Notice that I've dropped the `T` from `safeDivision`. In general, you should call function templates as if they were ordinary functions, without any scary angle brackets. Let type deduction do its thing.

If you *really* want to force the programmer to specify the `T` argument to `safeDivision`, then you should make it non-deducible. In C++20 you can do this with `type_identity_t`:

```
template<class T>
static T safeDivision(const std::type_identity_t<T>& f1, const std::type_identity_t<T>& f2);

safeDivision(1.0, 2.0);  // error, can't deduce T
safeDivision<double>(1.0, 2.0);  // OK
safeDivision<float>(1.0, 2.0);  // also OK
```

By the way, since `T` must be a floating-point type, you're losing performance via unnecessary pass-by-reference. Prefer pass-by-value for trivial primitive types like `float` and `long double`:

```
template<class T>
static T safeDivision(T a, T b);
```